# What type of situations cause the cin.get() function to not work?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm fairly new to c++ and I was wondering why my cin.get() isn't stopping the program in cmd from instantly closing when it's done? I tried the cin.get() on my previous code and it worked, but for some reason it doesn't work on this code.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
       using namespace std;
       int carrots;
       cout << "How many carrots do you have?" << endl;
       cin >> carrots;
       cout << "You have " << carrots << endl;
       cin.get();
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: You still have input in the input buffer. `get` only reads one character.

Comment: i figured it out, I needed to add another cin.get() apparently since the first pauses it when I ask for input and then a second is needed after that. But, what do you mean by input buffer?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/

Comment: I just wrote a function called `holdScreen()` where I use `getline()` to wait for an enter press.s

Comment: @user3720526, Input is kept in a buffer and extraction functions take it from there. They don't generally read past what they need to. If you input one `int` and type "23 34", " 34" is still left there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `cin.get()`, you get only one of those characters, treated as char.
You would not able see the output as the command prompt will close as soon as the program finishes. Putting `cin.get()` forces the program to wait for the user to enter a key before it will close, and you can see now the output of your program.

```
 using namespace std;
       int carrots;
       cout << "How many carrots do you have?" << endl;
       cin >> carrots;
       cout << "You have " << carrots << endl;
       cin.get();
       cin.get();// add another one
       return 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to add

```
cin.ignore();
```

Before than

```
cin.get();
```

To clean the input buffer from the previously return !

Complete code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int carrots;
    cout << "How many carrots do you have?" << endl;
    cin >> carrots;
    cout << "You have " << carrots << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```